# rxjava consumes next element even after exception

Tags: scala, rx-java

Could someone explain why rxjava consumes the next element from an observable sequence after exception in "onNext" happen and even after "onError" is called?

Here is my simulation:

```
import java.util.concurrent.{TimeUnit, CountDownLatch}
import rx.lang.scala._

object Tests {
  val counter = new CountDownLatch(1)

  def buildStream(num: Int) = {
    Stream.range(1, num)
      .map {s =>
      println(s"[${Thread.currentThread().getId}] Taken: $s");
      s}
  }
  val stream = buildStream(10).toSeq
  stream.toObservable
    .subscribe(
      onNext = x => consume(x),
      onError = e => println(s"ERROR! $e"),
      onCompleted = () => {println("completed"); counter.countDown()}
    )

 def consume(x: Int) = {
    println(s"[${Thread.currentThread().getId}] consuming: $x")
    Thread.sleep(100)
    if (x == 5) {
      throw new Exception(s"[${Thread.currentThread().getId}] consume?! ha!")
    }
  }
  counter.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
}
```

and its result is the following, and you can see that item **#6** is taken from sequence after the exception is raised:

```
[39] consuming: 1
[39] Taken: 2
[39] consuming: 2
[39] Taken: 3
[39] consuming: 3
[39] Taken: 4
[39] consuming: 4
[39] Taken: 5
[39] consuming: 5
ERROR! java.lang.Exception: [39] consume?! ha!
[39] Taken: 6
res0: rx.lang.scala.Subscription
```

As far as I can understand my observable collection created from a regular sequence is "cold" and the next item should only be taken from the source sequence after the current one is successfully handled by the observer.
I could suspect some threading issue, but it would mean that "cold" is not that "cold" which cannot be true, also I can clearly see that the same thread ID is used all the time.

So why item **6** is taken from the sequence?!

Answer (score 0):

You `Observable` is a synchronized `Observable` which means the `Observer` can not prevent the `Observable` from generating the new elements. However, RxJava promises that `Observer` will not receive any message after `onError` or `onCompleted`. That's consistent with your example.

In the incoming 0.17.0, RxJava will solve this problem. You can review the discussion here: https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/issues/802